# Visual studio return type long instead of integer

Tags: visual-studio, types, fortran, intel-fortran

Yesterday I ran my program smoothly but today it appears the error.
Here is my simple program:

```
    program ekf_6x6
    implicit none
    !include 'hmeas.f90'
    double precision, allocatable, dimension (:,:,:)::eC, eK
    double precision, allocatable, dimension (:,:):: F_f,sV,P,Q,R,H,BK,BC,invM,A,eyea,eyea1,P12,V,U,invV,invVt
    double precision, allocatable, dimension (:):: F_f0, F_f1, F_f05
    double precision, allocatable, dimension (:)::val_invM,val_BK,val_BC,val_R,val_H,val_A
    integer job(6),ind(18)
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: bc_unknow,m_node_dof
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:)::col_ind_invM,pointerB_invM,pointerE_invM,row_ind_invM
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: col_ind_BC,pointerB_BC,pointerE_BC,row_ind_BC
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: col_ind_BK,pointerB_BK,pointerE_BK,row_ind_BK
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: col_ind_R,pointerB_R,pointerE_R,row_ind_R
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: col_ind_H,pointerB_H,pointerE_H,row_ind_H
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:):: col_ind_A,pointerB_A,pointerE_A,row_ind_A
    integer, allocatable, dimension (:,:):: enode
    integer nenode, ndof_u, nelmt, istate,ielmt,Nt,nstate,nmeas,nnz_BK,nnz_BC,nnz_invM,ndof,fileID,nnz_R,nnz_H,it, n_mid_node,info,sdof,nnz_A,i,j
    double precision,allocatable, dimension (:):: x,s,x1,z,z1
    double precision dt
    !integer(kind=8) :: tclock1, tclock2, clock_rate
    !real(kind=8) :: elapsed_time
    Nt=2001
    dt=1d-3
    nenode=9
    ndof=2
    end program ekf_6x6
```

In the local window, instead of integer for data type, the program return the long type. In the output window, it said:

```
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\Console3\Console3\Debug\Console3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2021.2.0\windows\redist\ia32_win\compiler\libifcoremdd.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'Console3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2021.2.0\windows\redist\ia32_win\compiler\libmmd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

The error from visual studio:

[image: The error from visual studio]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To help other people help you, please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you sure the program does not run? What is the output of your program? Run it in the command line. Which VS window or tab are you showing in the picture?

Comment: What do you mean by "the program return the long type"? The code you have given doesn't appear to return anything at all.